# Access vector of pointers to other vectors on a GPU

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda, gpu, cula

so this is a followup to a question i had, at the moment in a CPU version of some Code, i have many things that look like the following:

```
for(int i =0;i<N;i++){

    dgemm(A[i], B[i],C[i], Size[i][0], Size[i][1], Size[i][2], Size[i][3], 'N','T');

}
```

where A[i] will be a 2D matrix of some size.

I would like to be able to do this on a GPU using CULA (I'm not just doing multiplies, so i need the Linear ALgebra operations in CULA), so for example:

```
 for(int i =0;i<N;i++){
        status = culaDeviceDgemm('T', 'N', Size[i][0], Size[i][0], Size[i][0], alpha, GlobalMat_d[i], Size[i][0], NG_d[i], Size[i][0], beta, GG_d[i], Size[i][0]);
}
```

but I would like to store my B's on the GPU in advance at the start of the program as they dont change, so I need to have a vector that contains pointers to the set of vectors that make up my B's.

i currently have the following code that compiles:

```
double **GlobalFVecs_d;
double **GlobalFPVecs_d;

extern "C" void copyFNFVecs_(double **FNFVecs, int numpulsars, int numcoeff){


  cudaError_t err;
  GlobalFPVecs_d = (double **)malloc(numpulsars * sizeof(double*));
 err = cudaMalloc( (void ***)&GlobalFVecs_d, numpulsars*sizeof(double*) );
 checkCudaError(err);

    for(int i =0; i < numpulsars;i++){
         err = cudaMalloc( (void **) &(GlobalFPVecs_d[i]), numcoeff*numcoeff*sizeof(double) );
         checkCudaError(err);    
         err = cudaMemcpy( GlobalFPVecs_d[i], FNFVecs[i], sizeof(double)*numcoeff*numcoeff, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
         checkCudaError(err);   
        }

         err = cudaMemcpy( GlobalFVecs_d, GlobalFPVecs_d, sizeof(double*)*numpulsars, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
         checkCudaError(err);

}
```

but if i now try and access it with:

```
 dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
 dim3 dimGrid;//((G + dimBlock.x - 1) / dimBlock.x,(N + dimBlock.y - 1) / dimBlock.y);
 dimGrid.x=(numcoeff + dimBlock.x - 1)/dimBlock.x;
 dimGrid.y = (numcoeff + dimBlock.y - 1)/dimBlock.y;

 for(int i =0; i < numpulsars; i++){
    CopyPPFNF<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(PPFMVec_d, GlobalFVecs_d[i], numpulsars, numcoeff, i);
 }
```

it seg faults here, is this not how to get at the data?

The kernal function that i'm calling is just:

```
__global__ void CopyPPFNF(double *FNF_d, double *PPFNF_d, int numpulsars, int numcoeff, int thispulsar) {

    // Each thread computes one element of C
    // by accumulating results into Cvalue




    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    int subrow=row-thispulsar*numcoeff;
    int subcol=row-thispulsar*numcoeff;

     __syncthreads();
    if(row >= (thispulsar+1)*numcoeff || col >= (thispulsar+1)*numcoeff) return;
    if(row < thispulsar*numcoeff || col < thispulsar*numcoeff) return;


    FNF_d[row * numpulsars*numcoeff + col] += PPFNF_d[subrow*numcoeff+subcol];

}
```

What am i not doing right?  Note eventually I would also like to do as the first example, calling cula functions on each GlobalFVecs_d[i], but for now not even this works.

Do you think this is the best way to go about doing this?   If it were possible to just pass CULA functions a slice of a large continuous vector I could do that to, but i don't know if it supports that.

Cheers
Lindley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
CopyPPFNF<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(PPFMVec_d, GlobalFVecs_d[i], numpulsars, numcoeff, i);
```

to this:

```
CopyPPFNF<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(PPFMVec_d, GlobalFPVecs_d[i], numpulsars, numcoeff, i);
```

and I believe it will work.

Your methodology of handling pointers is mostly correct.  However, when you put `GlobalFVecs_d[i]` in the parameter list, you are forcing the kernel setup code (running on the host) to take `GlobalFVecs_d` (a device pointer, created with `cudaMalloc`), add an appropriately scaled `i` to the pointer value, and then *dereference the resultant pointer* to retrieve the value to pass as a parameter to the kernel.    But we are *not allowed* to dereference device pointers in host code.

However, because your methodology was mostly correct, you have a convenient *parallel array* of the *same pointers* that resides on the host.  This array (`GlobalFPVecs_d`) is something that we are allowed to dereference into, in host code, to retrieve the resultant device pointer, to pass to the kernel.

It's an interesting bug because normally kernels do not seg fault (although they may throw an error), so a seg fault on a kernel invocation line is unusual.  But in this case, the seg fault is occurring in the kernel setup code, not the kernel itself.

Comment: Thanks that worked, not much faster than what I had been doing, which was copying one big matrix over, and then creating individual matrices out of that big one for each iteration of the loop, but the code is a bit cleaner.